# In R, how to add TRUE / FALSE column if a value differs from previous or following value?

Tags: r

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
  status = c("good", "good", "good", "bad", "good", "good", "good")
)
```

Output:

```
  time status
1    1   good
2    2   good
3    3   good
4    4    bad
5    5   good
6    6   good
7    7   good
```

I would like to add a new column `statuschange` IF `status` differs from the row above or below. The output would look like this:

```
  time status statuschange
1    1   good   NA
2    2   good   TRUE
3    3   good   FALSE
4    4    bad   FALSE
5    5   good   FALSE
6    6   good   TRUE
7    7   good   NA
```

I have the sense that are lots of ways to do this, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: Try `library(dplyr); df %>% mutate(statuschange=ifelse(status==lag(status, default=NA) & status==lead(status, default=NA), TRUE, FALSE))`

Comment: @Khashaa - thanks for the comment. I wasn't able to install dplyr just now (`Warning in install.packages :  package ‘dplyr’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)`), but I'll figure that out soon and give this a try.

Comment: @Khashaa - I've installed `dplyr` and your comment suggestion also worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply `diff` to see if two entries are the same.  You want two of these diffs, to see if both entries around an element are the same:

```
> !(c(NA, diff(as.numeric(x$status))) | c(rev(diff(as.numeric(rev(x$status)))), NA))
[1]    NA  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE    NA
```

The first expression tells whether the prior element is different:

```
> c(NA, diff(as.numeric(x$status)))
[1] NA  0  0 -1  1  0  0
```

The second tells whether the following element is different:

```
> c(rev(diff(as.numeric(rev(x$status)))), NA)
[1]  0  0  1 -1  0  0 NA
```

The "or" operation `|` returns `TRUE` for nonzero, which means a leading or following element is different, so we then invert the result with the leading `!`.

Comment: As a follow up for anyone else, the `status` column must be a factor (I believe) - not a character - for this to work.

Comment: @AdamSmith You are correct.  This relies on the column being a factor (or numeric) and will not work with a character column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
   df$A <- rep(0,7)
    for(i in 2:6){
    df$A[i] <- ifelse(df$status[i]==df$status[i-1] 
                & df$status[i]==df$status[i+1],'TRUE','FALSE')
    }
    df
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using looping:

```
statuschange=as.character()
for(i in seq_along(df$status))
{
statuschange[i]<-df$status[i]==df$status[i-1] && df$status[i]==df$status[i+1]
} 
df$statuschange<-statuschange
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using `zoo::rollapply` to loop through the column:

```
> library(zoo)
> c(NA, rollapply(x$status, width=3, FUN=function(x) x[1]==x[2] & x[2]==x[3]), NA)
[1]    NA  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE    NA
```

What this does, is create a series of "windows" each of width 3, rolling across the data, and applies the function to each subset.  As the window is 3, we end up with a vector that is two elements shorter than the original column (`width - 1` shorter).  The endpoint `NA` values are then added with `c`.